# Согласование падежей при обобщающих словах

Tags: согласование

Как правильно: "средства управления и разделения данными"  или "средства управления и разделения данных"?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта неверны.

Правило [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_03](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_03)

§205. Управление при однородных членах предложения

При двух или нескольких управляющих словах **общее зависимое слово допустимо, когда каждое из управляющих слов требует того же падежа и предлога**, например: читать и конспектировать книгу; подбирать и готовить кадры; протравливать и яровизировать семена; надеяться и рассчитывать на помощь.

**Наличие общего зависимого слова при различном управлении нарушает грамматико-стилистическую норму**, например: «с помощью и в сотрудничестве с местными организациями» (ср. правильный вариант: с помощью местных организаций и в сотрудничестве с ними), «организация и руководство стачечной борьбой»; «в соответствии и на основе утвержденного плана»; «надеяться и верить в возможность»; «руководство и контроль за распределением гуманитарной помощи».

**Комментарий**

**Редактировать предложение  без контекста, как мне кажется, не имеет смысла.**

**Средства управления данными**  – это известное терминологическое сочетание.

Например: "Управление **данными**  включает следующие компоненты..."

**Разделение данных**  – это тоже термин, например: "Механизм разделения данных – относительно новая функциональная особенность...."

Непонятно  соотношение действий в приведенном предложении: управление данными  включает в себя их разделение или они независимы между собой (управление начинается с разделения).

Поэтому нужен полный текст, чтобы обеспечить корректность построения фразы (семантическую и грамматическую).